# How to uninstall Sitecore package

Tags: sitecore-client, packages

Is there any way to rollback the entire package after successful deployment?

As per my knowledge, one way is to delete all the Sitecore items from the CMS, dll's if any from the bin and patch config files from their respective folders manually.

Is there any way Sitecore provide to rollback the deployed package so that I can avoid manual activity..

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is **No** officially tool available , which provides such functionality but you can use the **Anti-Package** functionality of the Sitecore rocks:

https://www.sitecore.net/nl-be/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/trevor-campbell/posts/2013/02/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-management-part-1.aspx
https://sitecoresandbox.com/tag/anti-packages/

Also, you can check this blog:

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2014/02/10/package-history-v2-user-guide/

Read the below blog provided by the Sitecore to uninstall the Sitecore package manually:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/916660

Hope this will help you.